# Why is my innerHTML object not changing when assigned?

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

In my HTML file I have a header and 2 buttons under it:

```
<h4 align="center">August 2014</h4>
<img src="images/arrow_BW_thin_left.png" alt="Previous Month" id="left" onMouseUp="funcLeft()" style="cursor:pointer">
<img src="images/arrow_BW_thin_right.png" alt="Next Month" id="right" onMouseUp="funcRight()" style="cursor:pointer">
```

In my JavaScript document I have a function, "funcRight()" :

```
function funcRight() {
    var month = document.getElementsByTagName("h4").item(0);
    if (month.innerHTML == "August 2014"){
        month.innerHTML="September 2014";
    } else if (month.innerHTML == "September 2014"){
        month.innerHTML="October 2014";
    }
}
```

When I click the image, it does not change the innerHTML in any way. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe neither of the conditions is true.. what *is* the actual value of innerHTML when the handler is called?

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/rex2t0ty/

Comment: I found the problem.  To simplify the code I put the variable inside the function while I actually had it at the top of the file.  Once I put it in the function, everything worked.  Thanks for your help guys!

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer the usage of `addEventListener()` over inline `onClick`.

Here you have a working exaple of your code

```
document.querySelector("#right").addEventListener("click", funcRight);

function funcRight() {
    var month = document.getElementsByTagName("h4").item(0);
    if (month.innerHTML == "August 2014"){
        month.innerHTML="September 2014";
    } else if (month.innerHTML == "September 2014"){
        month.innerHTML="October 2014";
    }
}
```

And here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amjgxfhz/) to play with.